# CSS select last paragraph, with not following unordered list

Tags: css

I'd like to select the last `<p>` but only if the next sibling is *NOT* an `<ul>`

```
<!-- Select this p element -->
<div>
    <p>...</p>
    <img>
</div>

<!-- Do NOT this p element -->
<div>
    <p>...</p>
    <ul>...</ul>
</div>
```

This is not working:

```
<style>
    div p:last-of-type, div p:not(+ul) {
    ...
}
</style>
```

Comment: In this case, you're giving two different selector sa you put a coma between them

Comment: I don't think that can be done with CSS, you might need a bit of Javascript to check for siblings.

Comment: No...not with CSS - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this with pure CSS, if you really must select the next sibling NOT `<ul>`, you're going to have to resort of Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding there is no way to select such selector using only CSS. You should need some script to do it. Check below snippet which helps with simple jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).next().is('ul')) {
      $(this).addClass('color-red');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.color-red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <span>Some more text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="all">
<div>
    <p>1sst</p>
    <img>
</div>

<!-- Do NOT this p element -->
<div>
    <p>last p</p>
    <ul>...</ul>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$('.all div').children('p').last()
</script>
```